# Developer tools for cinnamon extensions (applets, desklets)

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Are there developer tools for cinnamon applets and desklets?

The only thing I could come up with is removing the desklet folder from `~/.local/share/cinnamon/desklets/{desklet}` copying the new one and restart cinnamon with `cinnamon --replace` and wait 20 secs until it restarts. After that I can check on the desktop whether my code works and possibly debug it based on the stdout and stderr. I can do this only from terminal since I cannot use sudo from the run configuration in webstorm as far as I know. Now this is very far from a good testing/developer environment... :S

Comment: What about http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/desklets/view/17 ?

Comment: @doktor5000 I don't know, I no longer use Mint+Cinnamon. Currently I am with Fedora+Gnome3. Post it as an answer and I'll accept. Maybe it helps to somebody.

Comment: @inferno: Done. I went the other way, tried (I really tried hard for a few days, installed lots of extensions, but in the end I still couldn't stand gnome shell) gnome3 and even in classic mode it's not really useable to me. On the other hand, cinnamon has all those settings that I used to change on gnome already preconfigured in a useable way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try applet called [Cinnamon Developer's Tools](http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/desklets/view/17) which provides easy access to
[Looking Glass](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/LookingGlass) (the integrated debugger for gnome shell). It also provides quick access to the content of `~/.xsession-errors`, many frequently used modules from `cinnamon-settings` and allows to inspect applets and extensions. It also provides a button to restart cinnamon.

Comment: It's definitely helpful, but the UI is buggy on my system (buttons go beyond the window border, window themes go bananas, etc.), and the fact that it's a desklet keeps it buried under all my windows. I was hoping there was some alternative container for desklets, but I haven't found any.